# XML vs Dictionary in python for searching and extracting

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I have a decently sized XML file that I am pulling from an API of monit, using the following code in Python.

```
file = urllib.request.urlopen(URL) #opening the XML URL
    data = file.read()
    file.close()
    list.append(parsedXML, xmltodict.parse(data)) #Parsing to dict the XML file created
```

I am using XMLtoDICT to convert the XML to a dictionary, since I figured that would be easier to search and extract from.  XMLtoDICT creates a nested, ordered dictionary, which is great.  However, I don't see an easy way to search each "layer" of a python dict and extract out an entire node.

Is there an easy way to search and pull out a dictionary node in python for editing?

For example, look at the XML below.  Once it is in the dictionary, I need to pull out every node that starts with "`<service`"  (There will be multiple ones in the full XML file) and run tests on that exact node, and perhaps changing values.
I will also need to search all the values in the dictionary, find a value, then get the parent node name of that value and extract the whole node.  Is that possible?

Or, should I just skip the dictionary entirely and use the XML directly?  If so, is there a python library for XML that supports all of those features?

Here is a sample of the XML data I am pulling:

```
    <monit>
    <server>
        <id>9d8b2a3d3618ccc38628f6d7b89ebfd8</id>
        <incarnation>1427714713</incarnation>
        <version>5.4</version>
        <uptime>44395</uptime>
        <poll>120</poll>
        <startdelay>0</startdelay>
        <localhostname>DMZ-Server</localhostname>
        <controlfile>/etc/monit/monitrc</controlfile>
        <httpd>
            <address>192.168.1.100</address>
            <port>2812</port>
            <ssl>0</ssl>
        </httpd>
    </server>
    <platform>
        <name>Linux</name>
        <release>2.6.32-34-pve</release>
        <version>#1 SMP Sat Nov 8 09:38:26 CET 2014</version>
        <machine>i686</machine>
        <cpu>8</cpu>
        <memory>3145728</memory>
        <swap>1048576</swap>
    </platform>
    <service type="3">
        <name>mmonit</name>
        <collected_sec>1427759050</collected_sec>
        <collected_usec>180381</collected_usec>
        <status>0</status>
        <status_hint>0</status_hint>
        <monitor>1</monitor>
        <monitormode>0</monitormode>
        <pendingaction>0</pendingaction>
        <pid>11481</pid>
        <ppid>1</ppid>
        <uptime>692522</uptime>
        <children>0</children>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any tree traversal algorithm will do the trick.

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Python

I would stick with XML and use lxml to parse and traverse the XML tree.

http://lxml.de/tutorial.html
http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-elementtree-class

I'm sure others here will suggest newer XML libraries, feel free to use those. LXML is the only one I'm familiar with.

Comment: Awesome, I will keep the file in XML and use LXML, it appears to have everything I need.

Answer (score 0):

For searching and extracting, I'd suggest to skip dictionary and simply work on the XML 'directly'. [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is a concept that proven to be powerful to traverse and get specific part of an XML document. For example, to get `<service>` element anywhere in the XML document you can simply say in XPath : `//service`

[LXML](http://lxml.de) as mentioned in the other answer, is one possible library option in python that [support XPath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method). For example :

```
from lxml import etree
xml_source = """<root>
    <server>
        <id>9d8b2a3d3618ccc38628f6d7b89ebfd8</id>
        <incarnation>1427714713</incarnation>
        <version>5.4</version>
        <uptime>44395</uptime>
        <poll>120</poll>
        <startdelay>0</startdelay>
        <localhostname>DMZ-Server</localhostname>
        <controlfile>/etc/monit/monitrc</controlfile>
        <httpd>
            <address>192.168.1.100</address>
            <port>2812</port>
            <ssl>0</ssl>
        </httpd>
    </server>
    <platform>
        <name>Linux</name>
        <release>2.6.32-34-pve</release>
        <version>#1 SMP Sat Nov 8 09:38:26 CET 2014</version>
        <machine>i686</machine>
        <cpu>8</cpu>
        <memory>3145728</memory>
        <swap>1048576</swap>
    </platform>
    <service type="3">
        <name>mmonit</name>
        <collected_sec>1427759050</collected_sec>
        <collected_usec>180381</collected_usec>
        <status>0</status>
        <status_hint>0</status_hint>
        <monitor>1</monitor>
        <monitormode>0</monitormode>
        <pendingaction>0</pendingaction>
        <pid>11481</pid>
        <ppid>1</ppid>
        <uptime>692522</uptime>
        <children>0</children>
    </service>
</root>"""

doc = etree.fromstring(xml_source)
service = doc.find('.//service')
#you can then operate on service as needed: 
#parse it to dictionary, or in this example print the markup
print(etree.tostring(service, pretty_print=True))
```